# Extract specific text lines and replace words or characters with Python

Tags: python

I'm new to python and I have a bit of trouble creating a script. I have a text file like this (simplified):

```
Not of interest
Not of interest    
-object[bla bla    
-bla bla    
-bla bla    
Not of interest    
Not of interest
```

**1)** I would like to extract all the rows that contain "-". I did it with

```
import sys
Input=open(sys.argv[1],'r')
Lines=open('Line', 'w')
with Input as file:
    for line in Input:
        if '-' in line:
            Lines.write(line)
Input.close()
Lines.close()
```

**Getting this**

```
-object[bla bla
-bla bla
-bla bla
```

**2)** In all lines extracted, replace "[" with "\n-". I did it with

```
import sys, re
Input=open(sys.argv[1],'r')
with Input as file:
    Output = Input.read()
    Output = Output.replace('[', '\n-')    
with open('Output', 'w') as file:    
    file.write(Output)
```

**Getting this**

```
-object
-bla bla
-bla bla
-bla bla
```

**3)** How can I merge all the passages of these two scripts into one?

**Thanking you** in advance for your help in this matter

Comment: `if - in line` that's not valid python syntax. Please read [ask]

Comment: `if '-' in line:` is valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
with open("input.txt", "r") as inputFile, open("output.txt", "w") as outputFile:
  for line in inputFile:
    if "-" in line:
      outputFile.write(line.replace('[', "\n-"))
```

To test this, I had to change your input files to be  a little more interesting:

**input.txt**

```
Not of interest
-object[bla bla
-no square brackets here
there's one [ here-
Not of interest
-and a trailing one here[
-there's-[-two-[-here-
hats[[[!
-I think the [expected input is [more like this
```

The output looks like this:

**output.txt**

```
-object
-bla bla
-no square brackets here there's one 
- here-
-and a trailing one here
-
-there's-
--two-
--here-
-I think the 
-expected input is 
-more like this
```

It's pretty simple, but let's break it down:

`with open("input.txt", "r") as inputFile, open("output.txt", "w") as outputFile:`

This opens a file in read mode for input, and other one in (truncate and) write mode for output. It's in a `with` block because you should pretty much always use open with `with`. You could potentially get errors when working with files, input or output, and the `with` handles that gracefully.

`for line in inputFile:`

Using the inputFile as an iterator, step through it line by line. I didn't name this file stream `input` because that's already the name of the builtin Python keyword `input()`. Wouldn't want to confuse ourselves.

`if "-" in line:`

Check the line to see if it contains a "-", and proceed if it does. If not, do nothing and move on to the next line.

`outputFile.write(line.replace('[', "\n-"))`

`write()` directly to the file, bypassing Python's `print()` interface. We're writing the same line that had a "-" on the previous line of code, but before we write it out we're replacing all of the '['s with "\n-"s.

As you can see, this is a pretty simple one if you can understand the logic and program flow. Only 4 lines.

Comment: Thank you so much! You really helped me a lot!

Answer (score 0):

This is one way you could go about it:

```
f = open("target.txt","r+")
d = f.readlines()
f.seek(0)
for i in d:
    if i != "line you want to remove...":
        f.write(i)
f.truncate()
f.close()
```

by reading through the line you could specify the line to remove

You will need to edit this a little to fit your specific needs but message me if you have any questions.
Hope this helped!

Comment: She doesn't want to remove all instances of a particular line, she wants to ignore all lines that don't have a hyphen.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!